PBRT4: added radiance per unit distance in volume scattering
I'm reading section 11.1 Volume Scattering Processes of PBRT4 and feel confused about equation 11.3. It  gives us total added radiance per unit distance by source function $L_s$

And $Ls$ is given by

Ok, $L_s$ consists of two parts. The first one is emission, which is easy to understand. But the second part is confusing. $\sigma_s(p, w)$ is scattering coefficient, which gives the scattered proportion of radiance per unit distance in direction w. So I think $L_s$ should be

$\sigma_s * L_i$ gives us the proportion of scattered radiance in direction $w_i$.
But all the tutorial I can find uses the same form as pbrt4. Is there something I have missed?
I will greatly appreciate any help.
